# Cannot send a notification email in Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen, lumen-5.3

I'm trying to send a notification email as follows:

```
$post= Post::findOrFail($id);

$user = new User(['email' => 'report@myapp.com']);

$user->notify(new ReportPost($post));
```

But this isn't working for some reason. No error, but I'm not receiving any email. But if I fetch a user from the database and try the same thing, it will work. Any idea?

I'm using Lumen 5.3 and I've included the Mail and Notification package from Laravel 5.3

Comment: I'm guessing you need to save the new User before notifying. Try: `User::create(...); $user->notify(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install `illuminate/notifications` as Lumen does not support notifications out of the box

more can be found at https://stevethomas.com.au/php/using-laravel-notifications-in-lumen.html